Is there a "How-To" for addressing comments?
I've often noted that new users don't understand that they should address their reply to a comment to the person that made the comment to which they are responding; i.e.:
DO THIS:  
@<username> blah, blah, blah  

NOT THIS:
blah, blah, blah

Is there a written protocol for this somewhere in SE??  I've looked through the Help documentation, but found nothing.

Don't recall looking at the comment "Help" link before but low and behold:

I didn't intend to make that image paste a confusing fake, but I kinda like it.  "Learn more about comments" is pretty in depth (but don't try clicking the one above, heh-heh).
A shame there isn't a complete index of the help docs.  Possibly the kids who make these kinds of decisions think indexes are just for books and old people ("No! We want this information to be found intuitively, and not allow our users to get confused by an alphabetic list").

Amazing how many times you can look at something, and not actually see it  :)

Commenting is a privilege, and consequently it is documented in the Help center in the Privileges section.
See the privilege comment everywhere. The link in the help text pointed out in the answer of goldilocks also directs to that page.
The following section seems to mostly address your question:

The following community members will be automatically notified of your comment:

the owner of the post you're commenting on
one additional user when your comment contains a @username1 reply

1 You can only @reply to users who have already left a comment, or edited the post. The first three non-whitespace characters in @username are used for name matching, starting from the most recent comment or edit. See How do comment replies work?

The link in the footnote above provides even more details about how to notify other users.

That doesn't seem to be an accurate description of how the notification process works...  I regularly get notifications for comments from users who haven't inserted the @user address.
